# Help remembering a weird TV show

Tags: story-identification, tv

Once again I have a half remembered show that is bugging me.

The show was a mystery of the week kind of show sort of like X-files but with a more comedic tone.
The show also featured a computer that was powered by the Rosetta stone, and a comic relief character who happened to be a pig human hybrid.

I watched it sometime between 2000 and 2005 in South Africa, but the show was clearly American.

Comment: powered by the actual Rosetta stone or a similar language translation ancient tablet? I ask because...searching for "Rosetta stone" and "computer" leads to lots of "Learn Spanish now!" results....may need more to go on. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question

Comment: That was the problem I had when I was looking for this show.  I think the actual Rosetta stone was being used as a sort of Magical CPU (don't quote me on that, I am paraphrasing what I remember).

Comment: For future reference, it may be useful to include details like whether it was live-action or animated, and whether the episodes were aired in half-hour or full-hour blocks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Could be [The Chronicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicle_(TV_series)) which aired in the US 2001-2.  It has a character named Sal the Pig-Boy.  You can see him & the rest of the cast in the pictures.

[image][image]

Comment: Bingo!  The people on this website never cease to amaze me.  Thank you so much

Comment: I like when @FuzzyBoots shows his research path, so here it is.  I saw that you were having trouble tracing the Rosetta stone angle, so I focused on the pig man.  After a couple of general pig man searches, I figured there may be a [TV tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PigMan) & saw _The Chronicle_ in the list.  Looked into it and got pictures, etc.